# where do I open this path: C:\Documents and settings\"Your user name"\Local Settings\temp

Tags: windows-7

I need to find this path to hopefully delete SpyHunter 4 which I told NOT to install but it did anyway and it will not Uninstall thru Control Panel. Where do I type in the path to open it and find the unwanted SpyHunter?  TY

Comment: Given that  path you WILL need FULL admin rights (if your  user is NOT in the admin group you will need to use an account that is) --Yes some folks still use a  'standard user' account for  themselves.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. Are you trying to figure out how to navigate to "C:\Documents and Settings\USERNAME\LocalSettings\temp" or are you asking for a general removal of SpyHunter4?

Comment: The "Documents and Settings" directory was particular to WinXP and earlier: in Win7 and later the equivalent folder is "Users" and the structure of user directories is different. You should find the precise location of the files: if they are running you can use Task Manager - I am surprised that it is in a Temp directory: this may contain installation files, but not normally installed files themselves. (Note: from the command line `echo %temp%` will tell you where the default Temp folder is.)

Answer (score 1):

Apparently you are trying to following instructions aimed at Windows XP not Windows 7.
The more straightforward way to access the equivalent folder in Windows 7, is through the Start menu, typing `%LOCALAPPDATA%` and pressing the ENTER/RETURN key (⏎) as pointed by @Tetsujin in the comment. Perhaps, the `Temp` folder you need to find is there.

As you appear to be dealing with a software that does not ease its removal, I also suggest a little digging into your user profile.

On Windows, a convenient way of refering to the folder containing the "user profile" is by means of the environment variable USERPROFILE. So, in Windows Vista/7/8/8.1/10, if you go to Windows Explorer, and type at the address bar `%USERPROFILE%\Documents` and press the ENTER/RETURN key (⏎) it will open your personal documents folder.

The folder you asks appears to be a layman's way to refer to a temporary folder in Windows XP. I don't know the software but I would suggest you to use Windows Explorer and try to inspect some folders at both `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local` and `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming`.

Comment: Simpler method. Click Start, type `%localappdata%` & hit Enter. The Temp folder is in there. [Roaming shouldn't have a temp folder, only Local]

Comment: @Tetsujin You are right! I think I missed the point while trying to point to alternate locations where an "unfriendly" software could try to hide. Your straight to the point instruction could make a direct and better answer.

Comment: Feel free to drop it into your own answer. The rest of your explanation makes perfect sense, adding mine as a separate answer would just be duplicating effort :)

Answer (score 0):

C:\Users\your user name\AppData\Local\Temp

This is the temp folder used for each user account, replace "your user name" with your actual user account name.

Hold down the Windows key and tap R, a run box will open, now either type or copy-paste that file path into the run box and hit enter, the folder should open.

For more suggestions on removing malware see the link below

https://superuser.com/a/157533/40928